# Join list of pairs in java

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I have doubts about joining 2 lists in java, or merging them. But I have to sort the list 1 and leave the value empty last. I have these 2 lists:

```
final Pair<String, String> server1 = new Pair<>("45.167.30.4", "11562");
        final Pair<String, String> server2 = new Pair<>("", "11562");
        final Pair<String, String> server3 = new Pair<>("xxxxx", "11562");

    final ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> valuesServidores = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>() {{
        add(server1);
        add(server2);
        add(server3);
    }};
```

Here I need my list to be sorted and return this:

```
("45.167.30.4", "11562")
("", "11562")
("xxxxx", "11562")

final Pair<String, String> input1 = new Pair<>(etServidor1.getText().toString(), etPorta1.getText().toString());
        final Pair<String, String> input2 = new Pair<>(etServidor2.getText().toString(), etPorta2.getText().toString());
        final Pair<String, String> input3 = new Pair<>(etServidor3.getText().toString(), etPorta3.getText().toString());

    final ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> valuesInput = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>() {{
        add(input1);
        add(input2);
        add(input3);
    }};
```

I need to join that ordered list with this last one with something that returns something like this:

```
("45.167.30.4", etServidor1.getText().toString(), 
("11562", etPorta1.getText().toString())
("xxxxx", etServidor2.getText().toString(), 
("11562", etPorta2.getText().toString())
("", etServidor3.getText().toString(), 
("11562", etPorta3.getText().toString())
```

So the main point is that I can't use index (Example: int i; i ++, etc.) I can only use java's APIS (Collections, List, Map, etc.) Can someone give me some light?

Comment: Is this a schoolwork assignment?

Comment: No. it is an exercise that I am trying to do but I am stuck.